# Coupling Pairs of Random Variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ and $\{Z_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ be sets of independent random variables with coupling $\{X^{\hat{}}_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$, $\{Z^{\hat{}}_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ respectively. It then states

$$\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^{\hat{}},\sum_{i=1}^{n} Z_i^{\hat{}}\big)\text{ is a coupling of } \big(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i,\sum_{i=1}^{n} Z_i\big)$$

which I don't understand. Any help would be appreciated. I am lost and I would really appreciate it if someone can help me prove this. In my notes this is given as Lemma and there is no prove for it.

Answer (score 0):

A coupling of random variables $X$ and $Y$ is just a pair of r.v. whose marginals distributions are the distrbution of $X$ and the distribution of $Y$. So the statement in question looks a bit tautological, but is clearly true.

Comment: Isn't it a bit more nuanced than that? Take R.V.'s $X_1$ and $X_2$ which are coupled using R.V. $u$, and $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ which are coupled using R.V. $v$. So $X_i(u)$ is identical to $X_i$ in distribution (same for $Y$'s). Does that automatically mean $(X_1(u)+X_2(u),Y_1(v)+Y_2(v))$ is identical in distribution to $(X_1+X_2,Y_1+Y_2)$? Maybe the proof is straightforward, but it still has to be shown.